# How do I display a CGRect on the screen?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I get this **CGRect** to show up when I run the program?

```
var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: show up where? what is the context? what did you try so far?

Comment: I'm new so not really sure where to go.  I just want it to show up on the simulator screen when I run it :)

Comment: create a `UIView`, maybe, and add it to the hierarchy?

Answer (score 2):

`CGRect` is used in iOS for describing a size of a view. `x` and `y` properties are used to where the view should start from and from there `width` and `height` is used to know its size.

Easiest example to show you this rect right now would be in some base generated UIViewController class, if you start up a project. Your `viewDidLoad` should look something like this to get a rectangle with 100 width and 100 height.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        let view = UIView(frame: rect)

        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }
```

And it should show up

Comment: Isn't this just a copy of my answer with some little changes? And also it isn't viewable.

Comment: Posted it and you had replied it at the same exact moment - so isn't yours copy-paste of mine? :)

Comment: Hover your mouse over the time and it shows the exact time to see witch one is the first. 4 minutes difference is not exact moment.  [A moment corresponded to 90 seconds.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiNt4Pb8f_jAhXM0KQKHYShCqUQFjABegQICxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMoment_(time)&usg=AOvVaw1xG5ZyxLb_kU582Seh03jz)

Answer (score 0):

`CGRect` is not UI representable, almost anything you see in iOS is a subclass of `UIView`. Each view has a frame representing by `CGRect`.

So for example you can add a `UIView` with your `CGRect` frame inside a view of viewController like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    let view = UIView(frame: rect)
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(view)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your expectations, but I try to answer

```
var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
YOUR_LABEL.text = rect.debugDescription //show rect value to label on simulator
```

debugDescription output is : (0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)

so the point that I understand is showing the value of "rect" on the UI right?

hopefully answer your problem